# Не могу привести значение всех слов в копии списка к нижнему регистру

Tags: python, list

Пытаюсь привести значение всех слов в копии списка к нижнему регистру, но не получается. Подскажите пожалуйста где я допустил ошибку.

Python 3.8.1

```
users = ['andrew', 'caRolina', 'davID', 'denis', 'yAKUT8', "jaNE",'AdMiN']
new_users = users[:]
for name in new_users:
    name = name.lower()
print(users)
print(new_users)
```

Ожидаемый результат

```
['andrew', 'caRolina', 'davID', 'denis', 'yAKUT8', 'jaNE', 'AdMiN']
['andrew', 'carolina', 'david', 'denis', 'yakut8', 'jane', 'admin']
```

Фактический результат

```
['andrew', 'caRolina', 'davID', 'denis', 'yAKUT8', 'jaNE', 'AdMiN']
['andrew', 'caRolina', 'davID', 'denis', 'yAKUT8', 'jaNE', 'AdMiN']
```

Comment: `new_users = [ name.lower() for name in users ]`

Comment: Попробуйте вместо new_users = users[:] написать new_users = users.copy(). Ваш вариант представляет собой срез первого списка, т.е второй список указывает на те же объекты, что и первый. Copy возвращает новые объекты, но с теми же значениями. Возможно это поможет.

Comment: `new_users = list(map(str.lower, users))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Python списки являются изменяемыми типами данных, поэтому Вы можете модифицировать элементы в процессе итерации, обращаясь к ним по индексу:

```py
for i in range(len(new_users)):
    new_users[i] = new_users[i].lower()
```

Либо используйте списковое включение для генерации нового списка, как предложил S. Nick:

```py
new_users = [ name.lower() for name in users ]
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)

Answer (score 0):

Замените вторую строку на

```
new_users = users.copy()
```

Объяснением этому является главный принцип ООП, а точнее его расширение в Python. В ООП всё является объектами. А переменные являются лишь ссылками на объекты. Написав new_users = users[:], вы добавили всего лишь новую ссылку на список, на который ссылается users. Метод списка copy() возвращает новый список, но с такими же значениями внутри него

Comment: `id(users); new_users = users[:]; id(new_users)`

Comment: [:] как ни странно тоже копирует список, поэтому в программах на питоне практически и не встречается copy(), всё делают через слайсы

Comment: @CrazyElf, я однажды видел статью на англоязычном Stack Overflow, где описывались методы копирования списков. Вариант с [:] описывался как самый ненадёжный(и что найти ему применение уже задача). Объяснить это можно уже написанным выше. Однако вариант с .copy там тоже не считался самым лучшим. Там показывались даже варианты, о существовании которых я не мог и предполагать. Например, метод copy.copy(). Прилагаю ссылку на источник https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list

Comment: @Cof.Cof. Нет, там не написано ничего такого, там написано, что у него "странный синтаксис", хотя для тех, кто регулярно пользуется слайсами, мне кажется это совершенно нормальный синтаксис. :)  В общем случае точные копии списков всё же просто не нужны обычно. Обработанные каким-то образом - другое дело.

Comment: @CrazyElf тут играют трудности перевода. Для кого-то странный, а для кого-то плохой.

Comment: @Cof.Cof. Нет. Weird - это именно "странный" или там "дикий", но никоим образом не "плохой" или там "неправильный".

Answer (score 0):

Основная проблема - это то, что когда вы пишете `name.lower()` вы создаёте новую строку и переменная `name` после присваивания ей этого значения начинает указывать на новую строку, а не на текущий элемент списка, на который она указывала до того. Обратно в текущий элемент списка `new_users` эта строка не помещается автоматически. Чтобы она там появилась, надо сделать явное присвоение текущему элементу списка. Таким образом, чтобы ваш код заработал минимальное исправление будет выглядеть, например, так:

```
users = ['andrew', 'caRolina', 'davID', 'denis', 'yAKUT8', "jaNE",'AdMiN']
new_users = users[:]
for i,name in enumerate(new_users):
    name = name.lower()
    new_users[i] = name
print(users)
print(new_users)
```

Но более pythonic-way, конечно, воспользоваться советами из других ответов и комментариев и написать всё в одну строку через `map` либо через `списковое включение`. Я просто объяснил что именно в вашем коде не срабатывает.

P.S. Кроме всего прочего, модифицировать "на ходу" именно тот список, по которому вы итерируетесь - не очень хорошая манера, лучше так не делать, хотя в данном случае это работает.

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснение)